# Unity-How to Keep the Player out of the Walls

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, procedural-programming

So I put together a procedural generated map, and when I click it, the map randomly changes. What it does is it loops through the plane and randomly generates a mesh depending on the square's placement compared to randomfillpercent. If the map coordinate is marked 1, it's a wall, and if it's 0, its open space. I'm having an issue where if I click the map, the player sphere ends up inside the randomly generated wall. I want to make it so if the player's position is equal to a map coordinate that's a wall, then move it down the map until it reaches open space. Unfortunately, I keep getting null reference errors. I anyone could give me some ideas, I would appreciate it. Here's my variables and my RandomFillMap function. I'm not showing the whole code. If there's something you need to see, let me know. Thank you.

```
public class MapGeneratorCave : MonoBehaviour {

public int width;
public int height;

public string seed;
public bool useRandomSeed;
public GameObject player;
int[,] playerPosition;

[Range(0, 100)]
public int randomFillPercent;

int[,] map;

void Start()
{
    GenerateMap();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        GenerateMap();
    }
}

void GenerateMap()
{
    map = new int[width, height];
    RandomFillMap();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        SmoothMap();
    }

    ProcessMap();

    int borderSize = 1;
    int[,] borderedMap = new int[width + borderSize * 2, height + borderSize * 2];

    for (int x = 0; x < borderedMap.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < borderedMap.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            if (x >= borderSize && x < width + borderSize && y >= borderSize && y < height + borderSize)
            {
                borderedMap[x, y] = map[x - borderSize, y - borderSize];
            }
            else
            {
                borderedMap[x, y] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    MeshGenerator meshGen = GetComponent<MeshGenerator>();
    meshGen.GenerateMesh(borderedMap, 1);
}



 void RandomFillMap()
{
    int playerX = (int)player.transform.position.x;
    int playerY = (int)player.transform.position.y;

    if (useRandomSeed)
    {
        seed = Time.time.ToString();
    }

    System.Random pseudoRandom = new System.Random(seed.GetHashCode());

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            if (x == 0 || x == width - 1 || y == 0 || y == height - 1)
            {
                map[x, y] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                map[x, y] = (pseudoRandom.Next(0, 100) < randomFillPercent) ? 1 : 0;
            }
            if (playerPosition[playerX, playerY] == map[x, y] && map[x, y] == 1) 
            {
                playerPosition[playerX, playerY] = map[x, y - 1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting null references because playerPosition[playerX, playerY] doesn't exist.

What you should be using instead of a multi dimensional array (int[,])  is a Vector2

Then you would do something like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        if (x == 0 || x == width - 1 || y == 0 || y == height - 1)
        {
            map[x, y] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            map[x, y] = (pseudoRandom.Next(0, 100) < randomFillPercent) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
}

while(map[playerPosition.x, playerPosition.y] == 1){  
    playerPosition.y --; 
    // make sure you aren't out of bounds and such
}
```

Comment: That seems to make sense, but when I click to randomly generate, there are still cases where the player is inside the mesh, and even when its outside it, there are invisible walls, like the walls from the previous maze never really left.

Comment: That sounds like a completely different set of issues from what you asked here.  When you re-generate your map make sure you are destroying all of the old game objects (meshes, colliders etc.) that made up the old map.